# User and Data Migration – Script to move files (Powershell & Robo Copy)

Tags: powershell, robocopy

We have two domains, for the purpose of this post I will call them domain1 and domain2. Within each domain we have a file server called fileserver1 and fileserver2

(Sample account name Joe Blogs)
domain 1 user accounts have userPrincipalName of Joeb@domain1.local

domain 2 user accounts have userPrincipalName of joeblogs@domain2.local
(So first 3 letters of the first name and then the last name)

There is a folder share on both files servers that gets mapped at logon. The folders represent the userPrincipalName so Joe Blogs folders look like...

Fileserver1 Joeb
Fileserver2 joeblogs

The problem I'm having is trying to migrate the data from fileserver1 to fileserver2 due to the change of usernames.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve been in this situation before. The option I went for was to use PowerShell to create output that could be used in a batch file with RoboCopy. From the information you’ve provided it looks like the Givennames and Surnames are likely to be a match in both domains, assuming this is the case the following command will demonstrate the suggestion:

Get-ADUser John.Milner | % { write $("robocopy " + "\fileServer1\users$\" +  $*.GivenName +  $*.Surname.Substring(0,1) + " " + "\fileServer2\users$\" +  $*.GivenName.Substring(0,3) +  $*.Surname + " /mir /r:1 /w:2 /NP /LOG+:C:\Support\UserData.log") }

Output example

robocopy \fileServer1\users$\JohnM \fileServer2\users$\JohMilner /mir /r:1 /w:2 /NP /LOG+:C:\Support\UserData.log

Comment: I just want to say a massive thank you for your help on this! That's exactly what I wanted. I've been working on my own script which I will add to this post for the benefit of others.

Comment: Glad to hear it! Please mark my answer as accepted - http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer